# javascript htmlencode in FireFox XUL not work?

Tags: javascript, xul

my code is:

```
function htmlEncode (str){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.textContent=str;
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

it can work well in other page, but not work in xul,who can help me?

**UPDATE:**

Answer is:

```
function htmlEncode (str){
    var div = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","div");
    div.textContent=str;
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to use [document.createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElementNS) instead.

Comment: This is nice because the encoded HTML you get back can be sent to an MVC controller method without causing and error and then you can use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlData) to decode. Thanks!